# Meaning of "What time do we got to do this at?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am struggling to understand the meaning of the following sentence:

> What time do we got to do this at?

I assume "do we got" means "do we have got". I guess they are asking at what time it has to be completed or how much time have they left. Is that so?

Answer (score 5):

"Got" or "have" should be avoided in this case because there is no "getting" involved.  "Must" is better.

```
What time must we do this at?
```

However, the use of "at" at the end of a sentence like this is nonstandard.  Thus,

```
What time must we do this?
```

or

```
At what time must we do this?
```

Answer (score 3):

"What time do we **got** to do this at?" is a colloquial way of saying "What time do we **have** to do this at?"

So they are asking at what time something must be done.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably used in say a school/college situation where student will have been talking about a class, and it's used instead of saying "At what time does that class take place?"

Comment: Also, "At what time does that class take place?" is used instead of saying "When does that class take place?", which is used instead of saying "When is that class?".